# Adding user input in Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, netbeans, user-input

I am new to JAVA and this is what I have to do:
Accept a set of marks (out of 100). The user should press the Enter button after each mark is entered and the mark should then be added to an ArrayList of Integers.
This is what I have so far:

```
int score = Integer.parseInt(marksinput.getText());
ArrayList<Integer> marks = new ArrayList();
Collections.addAll(marks, score);
String out = "";
String Out = null;
int[] studentmarks = {score};

for (int item : studentmarks) {
    marksoutput.setText(""+item);
}
if (score > 100) {
    marksoutput.setText("Enter marks\n out of 100");
}
```

This only adds one mark in the arraylist and I need user to input as many marks he wants. I know that my arraylist is wrong, which is why it only takes 1 number but I do not know how to make all the input numbers go in arraylist. What I have is that it takes the number and if user inputs another number, it just replaces the older number. I want it to display both the numbers not just one. Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance!☻☻
(This is not a duplicate even though others have the same title)

Comment: is this inside a loop? the code seem like it's missing a major element.

Comment: You're looking for a loop.

Comment: i have no idea how to make the loop and make the user input numbers as many times he wants

Comment: @SLaks yeah it seems we get so used to it, I just assumed it's in a loop already

Comment: @RamBhatti https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: Thank you I used that code and edited the code in my question but still displays same thing. What I have is that it takes the number and if user inputs another number, it just replaces the older number. I want it to display both the numbers not just one

Answer (score 1):

In case what you are after is a program that adds any integer typed by the user into an ArrayList, what you would have to do is the following:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while(true)
    ints.add(scanner.nextInt());
```

What this program will do, is let the user input any number and automatically puts it into an ArrayList for the user. These integers can then be accessed by using the *get* method from the ArrayList, like so:

```
ints.get(0);
```

Where the zero in the above code sample, indicates the index in the ArrayList from where you would like to retrieve an integer.

Since this website is not there to help people write entire programs, this is the very basics of the ArrayList I have given you.

The ArrayList is a subclass of List, which is why we can define the variable using List. The while loop in the above example will keep on going forever unless you add some logic to it. Should you want it to end after executing a certain amount of times, I would recommend using a for loop rather than a while loop.

Best regards,

Comment: Thank you but I already know that. What I am trying to do is get multiple inputs from user and display it in arraylist. What I have is that it  takes the number and if user inputs another number, it just replaces the older number. I want it to display both the numbers not just one

Comment: Are the marks inputted inside a string that looks something like this: "1, 2, 4, 3, 8, 2"?

Comment: Is this using some form of frame, perhaps from the javax library?

Comment: yes its on netbeans so, I m making it on JFrame Form

Comment: You would then need to create a listener that acts upon the user submitting their results. Inside that listener you would want to have the logic adding to the ArrayList. Whenever you submit, you would also want to make sure to remove the text from inside the field where you store the user input.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you are really new,

What you are looking for is a `for-loop`

From the Java documentation, he is the syntax of a `for-loop` in Java

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

**Initialization**: Obviously you want to start from 0

**Termination**: you want to stop after 100 inputs, so that's 99 (starting from zero)

**Increment**: you want to "count" one by one so `count++`

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
    //Ask user for input
    //read and add to the ArrayList
}
```

So before you enter the `for-loop` you need to initialize the `ArrayList`, and a `Scanner` to read input:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();

for(int counter=0; counter < 100; counter++) {
    System.out.println("please enter the " + counter + " number");
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    list.add(x);
}
```

Comment: ArrayList <Integer> marks = new ArrayList();
for (int score=0;score<=100;score++){
    String x=(marksinput.getText());
    marksoutput.setText(x); Still doesnt work